# How do I authenticate into Gmail using Perl?

Tags: perl, module, gmail, login-script, authentication

I've installed [this](http://search.cpan.org/~mincus/Mail-Webmail-Gmail-1.09/lib/Mail/Webmail/Gmail.pm) module to gain access and controls within a Gmail inbox.  However, when I try to connect through a small Perl script and test the functionality, I get this error message.

```
Error: Could not login with those credentials - could not find final URL
  Additionally, HTTP error: 200 OK
```

This is an error built within the Gmail.pm module.

I can ping the URL in question ( https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBoxAuth ) so I feel that the trouble isn't finding the URL.  Furthermore, I know the credentials are correct and work at that URL because I have tried them manually.

I'm using [this](http://search.cpan.org/~mincus/Mail-Webmail-Gmail-1.09/lib/Mail/Webmail/Gmail.pm#SAMPLE_TEST_SCRIPTS) script for testing.  I have supplied my credentials in the appropriate places.

---

I've also installed [this](http://search.cpan.org/~mishoo/Net-IMAP-Client-0.93/lib/Net/IMAP/Client.pm) module with the same type of error.
Any idea why I'm getting blocked?

Comment: That distribution hasn't been updated since 2006; GMail has changed a lot in that time. Why not just use IMAP?

Comment: didn't see that 2006 date.... thanks for letting me know.... where can I find an IMAP module?  or do I even need one

Comment: im not too fond on accessing & parsing email boxes as you might notice by my last question post that got shot down

Comment: Net::IMAP::Client looks pretty complete, but I haven't personally used it. http://search.cpan.org/~mishoo/Net-IMAP-Client-0.93/lib/Net/IMAP/Client.pm

Comment: Cant connect using that one either - "Could not connect to IMAP server"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Mail-IMAPClient&mode=all) as shown below. To get pass SSL authentication through Mail::IMAPClient, you should have IO::Socket::SSL from Net::SSLeay installed. If so this works like a charm.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Mail::IMAPClient;

# Connect to IMAP server
my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
  Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
  User     => 'yourusername',
  Password => 'yourp4a55w0r&',
  Port     => 993,
  Ssl      =>  1,
  )
  or die "Cannot connect through IMAPClient: $!";

# List folders on remote server (see if all is ok)
if ( $client->IsAuthenticated() ) {
  print "Folders:\n";
  print "- ", $_, "\n" for @{ $client->folders() };  
};

# Say so long
$client->logout();
```

Comment: whats the method(s) to parse messages?

Comment: @Krebs Why should I prefer to display $EVAL_ERROR ($@) rather than $ERRNO ($!) which, printed as a string, yields the error string of the last system or library call. $@ is set if a string to be eval'ed did not compile (i.e. spots syntax errors).

Comment: @i-blis "you should have IO::Socket::SSL from Net::SSLeay installed" implies that installing Net::SSLeay will pull in IO::Socket::SSL but the reverse is true (meaning that IO::Socket:SSL depends upon Net::SSLeay) as indicated by http://deps.cpantesters.org/depended-on-by.pl?module=Net%3A%3ASSLeay

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me too (note to rookies: sudo cpan Mail::IMAPClient)

Answer (score 2):

I am successfully accessing a gmail account (google apps account to be precise) using Mail::POP3Client

Comment: thanks.... looks like it might be connecting (no error msgs) but it doesn't output anything as per the first example code listed at cpan

Comment: did you enable POP3 access in your gmail account?  

PROTIP: if you don't want to alter the state of your inbox, use the 'recent' tag in your uid:  http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47948

Comment: Did you check the return $pop->Count() after connecting?  -1 indicates an error, otherwise you're in busienss

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot access gmail through normal POP3 or IMAP either, then you have a configuration problem rather than a programming problem.

I fetch my mail from gmail (actually Google Apps, which uses the same interface), using configuration details described here: http://download.gna.org/hpr/fetchmail/FAQ/gmail-pop-howto.html

(This answer is far more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) though!)

Answer (score 0):

You can tried with the following module

```
  Mail::Webmail::Gmail
```

Comment: This is what he did. But the module is most probably out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code also

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mail::POP3Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use CGI qw(:standard);
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $LOG ;
open $LOG , ">>filename" ;
my $username  = 'name@gmail.com';
my $password  = '*******' ;
 chomp($password);
my $mailhost  = 'pop.gmail.com';
my $port      = '995';

$cgi->header();

my $pop = new Mail::POP3Client(
USER     => $username,
PASSWORD => $password,
HOST     => $mailhost,
PORT     => $port,
USESSL   => 'true',
DEBUG     => 0,
);
if (($pop->Count()) < 1) {
exit;
}

print $pop->Count() . " messages found!:$!\n";

for(my $i = 1; $i <= $pop->Count(); $i++) {
 foreach($pop->Head($i)) {
 /^(From|Subject|Email):\s+/i && print $_, "\n";
 }

$pop->BodyToFile($LOG,$i);

}

$pop->Close();

exit;
```