# How to connect to a Gmail inbox

Tags: perl, gmail, imap

I am currently trying to connect to a gmail inbox using Perl and
[`Net::IMAP::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Client)
with the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::IMAP::Client;

my $user = '[address]@gmail.com';
my $pwd = '[password]';

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
    server          => 'imap.gmail.com',
    user            => $user,
    pass            => $pwd,
    ssl             => 1,                     # (use SSL? default no)
    ssl_verify_peer => 0,                     # (use ca to verify server, default yes)
    port            => 993                    # (but defaults are sane)
) or die "Could not connect to IMAP server: $_";

$imap->login or
  die('Login failed: ' . $imap->last_error)
```

But the `$imap` variable is `undef` and I am getting this error:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at testIMAP.pl line 9.
>   Could not connect to IMAP server:  at testIMAP.pl line 9.

I have successfully connected to the mailbox using Outlook, but as I'm not getting an error message I'm not sure where to look. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I seem to get the same result regardless of what I put as the *username*. I believe if it was just the wrong details it would give me an 'Invalid credentials' error. But the $imap object isn't being created at all (is undef).

Comment: That is correct, it should give you something.  Don't know.  I literally copy-pasted your script, changed only the credentials, and it worked.  I'll look through the module docs for ways to troubleshoot ... Also, it may be worthed checking your gmail settings, in regards to certificates and such.  (Maybe it could be that it is set to require that or some such extra stuff?) Double verification?  (Or whatever they call it.)  I'd first look into gmail.

Comment: Thanks, will do. However I assumed that being able to log into Outlook meant settings should be ok, as Google considers it a 'less secure app'

Comment: Well, yes, you'd expect _something_ back.  It's strange that it fails like that.  (I searched for "problem" and such words with this module and the funny thing is that I get _nothing_.  Good module so it seems.)

Comment: Wait ... why is there `$_` in `die`?  I didn't notice that.  You want `$!` (or perhaps another error variable).  The `$_` shouldn't be set here. The `$!` _should_ have a reason for failure.

Comment: Ah nice catch! error is now "Network is unreachable". I'm able to 'ping' and  'telnet imap.gmail.com 993' successfully.

Comment: OK. A different ballgame. So ... I'd first try to get any web page via Perl, say with `LWP`.  Then, it seems that the module uses `IO::Socket::INET` module to get the connection.  (See in its [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GANGLION/Net-IMAP-Client-0.9505/lib/Net/IMAP/Client.pm) the sub `_get_socket`.) So, I'd try the simplest program with that module, to get out and connect somewhere. Perhaps first search its docs (and Google, with that module?) for 'Network is unreachable' error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139440/discussion-between-gnippots-and-zdim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big thanks to zdim for help troubleshooting.

Firstly, zdim pointed out that I had the incorrect error variable. $_ should have been $!

This revealed the error message "Network is unreachable", however I was able to pint and telnet to 'imap.gmail.com' successfully.

The solution to this was found here
[Perl IO::Socket::SSL: connect: Network is unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463748/perl-iosocketssl-connect-network-is-unreachable) .

Changing the use statement in the Net::IMAP::Client module to the following worked:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL 'inet4';
```

After this, the connection was established, but the login would fail with

```
Login failed: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

This is due to Gmail's security features. I received an email that allowed me to confirm that the connection was not malicious, and then subsequent logins were successful.

For others, there may be a few solutions to this last one. You may need to issue an 'app password' If two-step authentication is activated, or you might need to toggle on 'allow less secure apps'